# How did no one exiting the Hogwarts Express bump into Harry under his Invisibility Cloak?

Tags: harry-potter

When Harry was on the Hogwarts Express trying to look through Draco’s belongings, how was nobody bumping into Harry when everyone was getting off?

Answer (score 6):

Harry had climbed up onto the luggage rack, hence why Draco keeps looking upwards.

> Blaise shakes his head, smiling as he looks out the
>   window at the darkness. **Just then the small bag in the
>   upper rack shifts. Malfoy’s eyes play over it.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Half-Blood Prince - Script](http://www.cinefile.biz/script/potter6.pdf)</sup></sub>

[image]

On arrival at Hogwarts, Draco waits *until everyone has disembarked* and then zaps Harry, who then falls into the gangway.

> Malfoy wheels, points his wand at the luggage rack. Something hits the
>   floor with a THUMP. The Invisibility Cloak slips away and reveals
>   Harry, paralyzed on the floor. Malfoy grins.
>
> <sub><sup>[Half-Blood Prince - Script](http://www.cinefile.biz/script/potter6.pdf)</sup></sub>

---

Much the same happens in the book, other than that it's Harry's ankle that gives the game away to Malfoy, not the shifting of the bag

> Harry darted into the compartment, leapt on to Zabini’s temporarily
>   empty seat and hoisted himself up into the luggage rack. It was
>   fortunate that Goyle and Zabini were snarling at each other, drawing
>   all eyes on to them, for **Harry was quite sure his feet and ankles had
>   been revealed as the Cloak had flapped around them; indeed, for one
>   horrible moment he thought he saw Malfoy’s eyes follow his trainer as
>   it whipped upwards out of sight;**
>
> <sub><sup>[Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Half-Blood_Prince)</sup></sub>

and confirmed when Harry gets hit with some luggage

> Harry was so busy staring at Malfoy he did not notice Goyle reaching
>   up for his trunk; as he swung it down, it hit Harry hard on the side
>   of the head. He let out an involuntary gasp of pain and Malfoy looked
>   up at the luggage rack, frowning.
>
> <sub><sup>[Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Half-Blood_Prince)</sup></sub>

Malfoy then waited until the train was empty before petrifying Harry.

> ‘***Petrificus Totalus!’***
>   Without warning, Malfoy pointed his wand at Harry, who was instantly paralysed. As though in slow motion, he toppled out of the luggage rack and fell, with an agonising, floor-shaking crash, at Malfoy’s feet, the Invisibility Cloak trapped beneath him, his whole body revealed with his legs still curled absurdly into the cramped kneeling position. He couldn’t move a muscle; he could only gaze up at Malfoy, who smiled broadly.
>   ‘I thought so,’ he said jubilantly. ‘I heard Goyle’s trunk hit you. And I thought I saw something white flash through the air after Zabini came back …’ His eyes lingered for a moment upon Harry’s trainers. ‘That was you blocking the door when Zabini came back in, I suppose?’
>
> <sub><sup>[Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Half-Blood_Prince)</sup></sub>

Comment: Oh, so Harry had been laying on the rack until everyone had gone off

Comment: But that doesn’t make sense, if he had climbed up there his feet would’ve been visible when he would climb up there

Comment: @JordanCarreira - In the book, that was precisely what happened.